# Bind a GridView to a GridView object in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, binding

I'm quiet new in MVVM, and I have a little probleme I can't solve.
I have a GridView and I would like to bind it to a GridView object in my viewmodel (which is separated from the code behind file of my XAML file).

But there's no attribute I can't write with {Binding ...}, and I dont want to give it in the arguments of the initialization of my view model.

I want to have access to all the properties of my GridView in the viewmodel, to get the selecteditem(s).

Thanks

Comment: Post your current code and XAML

Answer (score 2):

The gridview class represents a view mode that displays data items in columns for a ListView control.  About the only useful thing you can bind on the gridview is the Columns property.

If you want to bind rows for the gridview, bind at the listview level to the ItemsSource property.